# How can download oracle apex report as PDF?

Tags: oracle, pdf, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a Interactive Report page on oracle apex 5.1.4 on my local environment [ windows 10]. I have retrieved data on that page using custom SQL query from different tables. Now I want to download report as  PDF using Download option [ Image-1 ]. PDF file is downloading fine but PDF file is not opening.  [ Image-2 ]

Note that, In the Instance Settings- Print Server is selected as External Apache (FOP).

I did not get any resources on this topic, Any solution?

[image: Image-1: Result after filtering to download as PDF]
[image: Image-2: PDF not opening]

Answer (score 2):

If the setting is set to external print server, do you have a print server configured? has that print server been verified to work correctly?

If these are not true, then have you configured apex to use ORDS? If yes then you should be able to set the print server settings to ORDS. You do not get a ton of configuration options out of the box, but you do get a PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Dimitri Gielis' blog, [Export your APEX Interactive Report to PDF](http://dgielis.blogspot.hr/2016/06/export-your-apex-interactive-report-to.html). It seems that your case is described in his case #2:

> ... you will need to **configure a print server** like BI Publisher or
>   Apache-FOP.

How to configure it? No idea, it's beyond my knowledge.

Comment: BI Publisher is a commercial product from Oracle; of course Apache-FOP is open source and documented at https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/ but how to configure it to work with Apex I am clueless too.